# p:textEditor Tag not Working Properly

Tags: primefaces, dialog, text-editor

When I insert the p:textEditor tag in a p:dialog, many of the buttons / select lists in the *toolbar* do *not* work.

Following steps to reproduce the problem:

- I click the appropriate button to open (launch) the dialog.
- I type some text in the text editor area.
- I then select / highlight some of the text I just typed
- I click on the Font-size selection drop-down to select a different
  font-size (such as "Large").
- Nothing happens. The text I selected remains the same. No change.

Strangely enough, if I exit the dialog then reopen the dialog, the selection lists and buttons in the toolbar work fine. Apparently, it is just that *first* time that I open the dialog that the toolbar buttons do not work.

Also, I tried inserting the p:textEditor tag on the main form - not in the dialog - and it works fine on the main form. In other words, when the p:textEditor tag is outside of a  p:dialog, it seems to work fine. The problems only seem to occur when the p:textEditor tag is *inside* a  p:dialog. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

JSF 2.2
Primefaces 6.2
GlassFish Server 4.1.1
Netbeans 8.2

Update: Hi. I was able to reproduce the problem with the following code. The problem seems to surface when I use the "update" attribute in the p:commandbutton button that launches the dialog.- Ian

===============  Here is JSF file======================================

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="Login" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show();" update=":loginForm"   >
                <p:resetInput target=":loginForm" />     
            </p:commandButton>   
        </h:form>

            <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" life="3000" />

            <p:dialog header="Login" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">
                <h:form id="loginForm">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                        <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
                        <p:inputText id="username" value="#{userLoginView.username}" required="true" label="username" />

                        <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
                        <p:password id="password" value="#{userLoginView.password}" required="true" label="password" />

                        <h:outputLabel for="comment" value="Comment:" />
                        <p:textEditor widgetVar="txtEditor1" id="comment" value="#{userLoginView.text1}" height="100" style="margin-bottom:10px;margin-right:10px;" placeholder="Enter your content">
                        </p:textEditor> 

                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <p:commandButton value="Login" update="growl" actionListener="#{userLoginView.login}"
                                             oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)" />
                        </f:facet>  
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {
                if(args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn) {
                    PF('dlg').jq.effect("shake", {times:5}, 100);
                }
                else {
                    PF('dlg').hide();
                    $('#loginLink').fadeOut();
                }
            }
        </script>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

=====================================================================

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package demo;

/**
 *
 * @author admin
 */
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.primefaces.PrimeFaces;

@ManagedBean
public class UserLoginView {

    private String username;

    private String password;
    private String text1;

    public String getText1() {
        return text1;
    }

    public void setText1(String text1) {
        this.text1 = text1;
    }



    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void login(ActionEvent event) {
        FacesMessage message = null;
        boolean loggedIn = false;

        if(username != null && username.equals("admin") && password != null && password.equals("admin")) {
            loggedIn = true;
            message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Welcome", username);
        } else {
            loggedIn = false;
            message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Loggin Error", "Invalid credentials");
        }

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().addCallbackParam("loggedIn", loggedIn);
    }   
}
```

Comment: How can I reproduce? There is no [mcve] like requested in [ask]... Please create one

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you still have the problem but it is possible to work around it by opening and closing the dialog in a @PostConstruct method.
It is transparent for the user but still, a more viable solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Gorgo. I'll give it a try.

Comment: P.S. I am not sure how I would do this: open and close the dialog in @PostConstruct method. By chance, do you have a code snippet with an example you can share with me? That would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. You can go for something like :
   `@PostConstruct`

    `init(){`

    `PrimeFaces current = PrimeFaces.current();`

    `current.executeScript("PF('myDialogVar').show();");`

    `current.executeScript("PF('myDialogVar').hide();");`

`}`

Comment: Thanks, Gorgo. I will give it a whirl. Regards.